# Sum of only unique Date rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like that

| week | co_week | Revenue | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19/09/2021 | 01/10/2021 | 120 | US |
| 19/09/2021 | 03/10/2021 | 120 | US |
| 19/09/2021 | 03/10/2021 | 120 | FR |
| 20/09/2021 | 05/10/2021 | 15 | US |
| 20/09/2021 | 06/10/2021 | 34 | FR |

Now I'd like to get the sum of Revenue for each unique week date , so the output should look like that

| week | co_week | Revenue | Total_revenue | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19/09/2021 | 01/10/2021 | 120 | 135 | US |
| 19/09/2021 | 03/10/2021 | 120 | 135 | US |
| 19/09/2021 | 03/10/2021 | 120 | 154 | FR |
| 20/09/2021 | 05/10/2021 | 15 | 135 | US |
| 20/09/2021 | 06/10/2021 | 34 | 154 | FR |

I tried using the following code , but I ended with a lot of Null values in the new column due to the dropping of most indexes!

```
df['Total_revenue'] = df.drop_duplicates(['Revenue']).groupby(df['Country'])['Total_spend'].transform('sum')
```

Comment: Looks like you need to `df.groupby('week')['Revenue'].sum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you might want to [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) in the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df['Total_revenue'] = (df.groupby('Country')['Revenue']
                         .transform(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates().sum())
                       )
```

But this might be biased if you have several times the same revenue on different weeks **by chance**.

Better use a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) to hide the duplicated values, then `groupby.transform('sum')`:

```
df['Total_revenue'] = (df['Revenue']
                       .mask(df.duplicated(['week', 'Country']))
                       .groupby(df['Country']).transform('sum')
                       )
```

output:

```
         week     co_week  Revenue Country  Total_revenue
0  19/09/2021  01/10/2021      120      US            135
1  19/09/2021  03/10/2021      120      US            135
2  19/09/2021  03/10/2021      120      FR            154
3  20/09/2021  05/10/2021       15      US            135
4  20/09/2021  06/10/2021       34      FR            154
```